# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK is not set

Tags: debian, iptables, kernel

I am trying to setup iptables on udoo quad but I hit a brick wall and cannot find a fix anywhere:

```
root@udoo:/# uname -a
Linux udoo 3.0.35 #10 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 30 18:16:10 CEST 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux

root@udoo:/tmp# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
root@udoo:/tmp# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
root@udoo:/tmp# iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
root@udoo:/tmp# cd /tmp
root@udoo:/tmp# cp /proc/config.gz .
root@udoo:/tmp# gunzip config.gz
root@udoo:/tmp# grep CONNTRACK config
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK is not set
```

How do I add the module to the kernel? ... or do I need to compile new kernel?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thx

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to (cross) compile a new kernel.

Comment: I was affraid that might be the case. I was hoping the necessary module can be dynamically compiled and loaded